# Curl -H flag in php

Tags: php, curl

I have to make a call to an API and I have the terminal command that works but I can't seem to make it work with php (I get 403 forbidden error). This is the call that works:

```
curl -X GET -H "mail: mail@api.com" -H "password: XXX" "http://api.com/rest/v1"
```

This is what I have in PHP so far:

```
$url = "http://api.com/rest/v1"; 

$headers = array( 
    "Content-type: application/json", 
    "Accept: application/json", 
); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$auth = array('mail: mail@api.com', 'password: XXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($auth)); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch); 
} else { 
    // Show me the result 
    var_dump($data); 
    curl_close($ch); 
}
```

The var_dump shows bool(true) but I also get the 403 error message. I also tried adding the email/password in the headers but didn't work. Like this (and removing the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS line):

```
$headers = array( 
    "Content-type: application/json", 
    "Accept: application/json", 
    'mail: mail@api.com', 
    'password: XXX'
);
```

Comment: You're not using the `$headers` anywhere, you need to set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had it commented out, but I uncommented it and still same issue, I'll update the question

Comment: I'd like to know why the downvoting :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-H is a header for the curl command line, so why are you setting them as the postfields?

Seems like it should be:

```
$headers =  array('mail: mail@api.com', 'password: XXX');
```

This should be the same as your CLI command above.  If this doesn't work, check the output of curl_exec() to see what the server is responding.

Comment: I didn't understand very well what the -H meant, this works now, I also had a spelling mistake so it's a bit of both, thank you.